# How to get rid of #2038 error in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

Here is my code:
I have created an flex mobile app in which I want to save a file in pdf format in an ipad/iphone (any IOS device)
but while saving that file its throughing #2038 error.
Here is my code.

```
var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("indicators.pdf");

if (file.exists)
 file.deleteFile(); //delete it if exists
//create a file stream to be able to write the content of the file    
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();

var popUpPage:AlertPage = new AlertPage();

try
{
 //open the file stream and set for Write
 fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
 //writes the bytes
 fileStream.writeBytes(pdfBytes, 0, pdfBytes.length);
 //close the stream
 fileStream.close();

 PopUpManager.addPopUp(popUpPage,this,true);
 popUpPage.lblAlert.text = "indicator saved in pdf format = "+ file.nativePath;
 PopUpManager.centerPopUp(popUpPage);
 this.visible = false;
}
catch(err :Error)
{
 PopUpManager.addPopUp(popUpPage,this,true);
 popUpPage.lblAlert.text = err.message + "  "+ file.nativePath;
 PopUpManager.centerPopUp(popUpPage);
}
```

Comment: What is your full error?  what line causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save to `desktopDirectory` on any mobile device. Your app is permitted to save only to `applicationStorageDirectory`. What you have there will error out every time for that reason.

As a simple trick, you should do this to allow both.

```
private const isDesktop:Boolean = false;
private var baseDirectory:File = ( isDesktop ) ? File.desktopDirectory:File.applicationStorageDirectory;

//and to declare a file, do this
private var pdf:File = this.baseDirectory.resolvePath( 'blah.pdf' );
```

So you toggle the `isDesktop` property to choose which to use and the `baseDirectory` is declared accordingly. You then just resolve your path from the `baseDirectory` each time, rather than doing a hard coded `applicationStorageDirectory` or `desktopDirectory`.

This method is much more flexible for debugging in the long run.

Comment: @Apocaliptic yeah I know that we can store the .pdf file in applicationstoragedirectory, but than I can only use that pdf file programmatically.
And I can't see that file any where in the ipad.  And one thing this .pdf file is saving perfectly in an android device but it is showing this
#2038 error in an ipad.

Comment: @Nishant Trace out `File.desktopDirectory.exists` on the iPad and see if it returns true or false. Everything I have read says it should return false. I've never even tried saving it anywhere but the `applicationStorageDirectory` simply because everything I have read says it is the only place we can save to.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how permissions work on Android BUT in our desktop environment (Flex-Desktop app), we were able to eliminate the error by fixing folder permissions (giving users permissions to read-write-modify)